# How to remap command abort (Ctrl-c)

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

When you run a command such as `:! sleep 5`, then you can normally cancel it using Ctrl-c. How do I remap that combination to something else, for example Ctrl-x?

The context is that I use urxvt with option `URxvt.keysym.C-c: eval:selection_to_clipboard` (along with `stty intr ^X`.) But this means that Ctrl-c doesn't get passed to vim, so Ctrl-c does nothing.

If I set `cmap <C-x> <C-c>` then Ctrl-x will cancel commands that I haven't started yet, but it does nothing after I've started the command.

Alternatively, is there any way to get escape to cancel a running command?

I'm on NVIM v0.4.4. Thank you.

Comment: When in terminal, Ctrl+c is the standard keybinding to send an interrupt signal to the running process. You will probably have to solve similar problems for all kinds of programs (not only vim) like aborting shell scripts or won't even be able to solve them. 

The benefits of overriding default behaviour often are not worth the new problems that arise long-term, and Ctrl+c as Interrupt definitively is such a case.

So I highly recommend using some other keybinding to copy a visual selection to clipboard, e.g. Ctrl+Shift+c.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but this is the first time I've run into `stty intr ^X` not working.

Comment: I've ended up solving this by configuring urxvt with `URxvt.keysym.C-x: \003` and not setting `stty intr ^X`. Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303258/464554

Answer (score 1):

When you issue `:!sleep 5`, Vim steps back and passes control to the shell. Quoting `:help :!`,

> **:!{cmd}** Execute {cmd} with the shell.

With `stty intr ^X` you have assigned the interrupt signal to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. Therefore, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> interrupts `:!sleep 5`. It's funny, but it's true: You already have what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately Ctrl X doesn't work, but Ctrl C *does* work if I remove the urxvt config, so somehow the `stty inty ^X` isn't making it through? I don't really understand the fine nuances of what `:!` does.

Comment: @C4K3 Hmm... If you open a terminal, issue `stty intr ^X;sleep 9` and type Ctrl-X, does it interrupt the sleep command? That would be the expected behavior. Then open a terminal again, `stty intr ^X;vim`, in Vim issue `:!sleep 9` and Ctrl-X, doesn't it interrupt the sleep command? `:!cmd` simply means "execute the command in the shell, that's not a Vim internal cmd".

Comment: `stty intr ^X;sleep 9` does get interrupted with Ctrl-X. `stty intr ^X;vim` and then `:!sleep 9` does not get interrupted by Ctrl-X. `:!stty intr ^X; sleep 2` gives `stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Comment: @C4K3 Sorry, I don't know what is going on then. You are not using Gvim, are you?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it though! No, I am not using Gvim.

Comment: Can I ask if it works for you? So I'll know if it's something with my environment.

Comment: @C4K3 Yeah, it works for me. Should have something to do with your environment, indeed... When your question is interfaced with the shell or terminal emulators, you might get more support at Unix&Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using vim instead of neovim and it works for me there.